# how to print product of vector in R

Tags: r, for-loop, product

So this is my current code:

```
vec_prod <- function(x){
     out <- 1
     for(i in 1:length(x)){
          out <- out*x[i]
     }
     out
 }
```

however, i want to print out the product of vector [2,3,5]

but it does not accept those values. I can only input (1:3) or (1:4)

I'm new to R programming so any help is appreciated. I do not want to use any other functions.

Comment: Also, it does not have to be [2,3,5] it can be any value that the user inputs.

Comment: `vec_prod(c(2,3,5))` works, but you can jut use existing function `prod` : `prod(c(2,3,5))`

Comment: "but it does not accept those values"  -- what does that even mean? `vec_prod(c(2,3,5))` works. `[2,3,4]` is not a vector literal in R. I'm voting to close this as off-topic since it is essentially just a typo in entering a vector to a function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue wasn't in function code, but probably in the way user called it. I propose my cleaner version. But you should really just use prod.

```
 vec_prod <- function(x){
   out <- 1
   for(i in x){
     out <- out*i
   }
   out
 }
 vex_prod(c(4,5,6))
```

Comment: your function does just the same as his, just cleaner

Comment: Yeah I thought he had made a mistake in his code. Which he hasn't Should I delete me answer?

Comment: no this code is working fine, you do not have to delete.

Comment: @RyanGarcia you can ask new questions separately. Not in the comments of an existing question.

Comment: I will, there is a timer for me to accept the answer @AbhisekRoy

Comment: @RyanGarcia you can just use max(c(1,23,12,41,4123,213)) to get the max number in a vector.

Comment: @Abhisek Roy , maybe mention that the issue wasn't in his function code, but ptobably in the way he called it, then propose your cleaner version. But OP should really just use `prod`

Comment: Obviously @Moody_Mudskipper. I wrote it only because he said not to use inbuilt functions.

Comment: @Moody_Mudskipper made the changes. Thanks for the advice.